# node.js write data to already connected net socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, dom-events

I am experimenting with node.js (no experience at all)...

I have this simple code to create a net socket:

```js
server_ip = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';
port = 8080;

var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(socket_connected_function);

server.listen(port, server_ip, false);

function socket_connected_function(socket) {
    socket.write('\nWELCOME\r\n');
    socket.pipe(socket);
}
```

So it writes that "welcome" message when a new connection is made, but how could I tell it to write something new inside this socket at a later time? E.g. send a message trough the socket when something happens on server.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it's a bit vague question. As a suggestion, you might want to look at [Events API](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/events.html) that can **emit** events and **subscribe** to events.